# How to configure pom files and TeamCity to build dependent modules in maven java project?

Tags: java, xml, maven, teamcity, pom.xml

I have project which consists from two modules. One of them considered to be main. So the second depends on first. Also I should generate javadoc jar files for modules. The output should be four .jar files: 2 module jar files and two javadoc jar files.

Locally, to generate both jar files I should repeat these step several times (I don't know why):

1. Build first one and install to local maven repository.
2. Then I can build second one.

Without installation of first modules I can't achieve packaging phase, because when I test second module it cannot find first module jar file.

Could I do all of these steps by one build process?

POMs which I have:

1. Parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
    <artifactId>repres</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>bingap</name>
    <modules>
        <module>mainmod</module>
        <module>secondmod</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
                <artifactId>repres</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

2. Main module pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
        <artifactId>repres</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>mainmod</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>mainmod</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportOutputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\javadoc\</reportOutputDirectory>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals><goal>test-jar</goal></goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--outputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\</outputDirectory>
                            <finalName>mainmod</finalName-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\</outputDirectory>
                            <finalName>mainmod-javadoc</finalName>
                            <classesDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\javadoc\apidocs\</classesDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

3. Second module pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>repres</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
    <artifactId>secondmod</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
            <artifactId>mainmod</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.bingap</groupId>
                <artifactId>mainmod</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>javadoc</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <reportOutputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\javadoc\</reportOutputDirectory>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>secondmod</id>
                            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\</outputDirectory>
                                <finalName>secondmod</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-secondmod-javadocs</id>
                            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\</outputDirectory>
                                <finalName>secondmod-javadoc</finalName>
                                <classesDirectory>out\artifacts\output_jar\javadoc\apidocs\</classesDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please make a github project of it so it's easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. The error was received because mainmod module was accessible for secondmod module only for test scope `<scope>test</scope>`. Then I added new dependency with same artifactId, groupId and version, but assigned compile scope. Of course, it shows me warning about repeatition. However, it solves the problem.
Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

You just call `mvn clean install` on the parent project. It will build both modules in the right order.

Comment: Error: java: package ru.bingap.mainmod does not exist

Comment: Aren't your parent and your modules in the same git repository?

Comment: Yes. They are in one repo.

Comment: You call `mvn clean install` on the parent project. This is the way to build Maven multi module projects. If this does not work, there is some error in your projects. To spot it, please add the log output of that command.